# Trying to set a string in a struct

Tags: c

```
struct list_el {
    unsigned int data;
    char name[16];
    char grade;
    struct list_el * next;
};

typedef struct list_el item;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    item *curr, *head;

    //first item
    curr->data = 3141592;
    strcpy(curr->name, "Carl");
    curr->grade = 'A';
    curr->next = head;
    head = curr;
```

Trying to figure out why this isn't working when I try to set name to "Carl". I'm getting "too few arguments to function 'strcpy'" even though I have 2 arguments in it (destination, source). When I add a 3rd argument (how many characters to copy?), I end up getting "assignment to expression with array type".

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you haven't allocated memory for `curr` before using it.

Comment: Not sure why this would fail to compile but it's definitely UB - you're declaring a pointer to an `item` but have not initialized it to an actual instance.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is preventing eclipse from building my project for me...

Comment: it's working after allocating memory x.x Thanks for the help! Wonder why it didn't give me an error for the rest of it...

Comment: Does you true code have `#include<string.h>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not getting your error "**too few arguments to function 'strcpy' "** but i can see that you have declare a **item *curr** but never initialized.So i tried with correcting this and updated your code as below and its not giving any error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct list_el {
    unsigned int data;
    char name[16];
    char grade;
    struct list_el * next;
};

typedef struct list_el item;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    item *curr, *head;
    curr = malloc(sizeof(struct list_el));
    //first item
    curr->data = 3141592;
    strcpy(curr->name, "Carl");
    curr->grade = 'A';
    curr->next = head;
    head = curr;
}
```

I think, it will work for you.

Comment: Idea:  rather than `curr = malloc(sizeof(struct list_el));`, consider `curr = malloc(sizeof *curr);`  Easier to code, less likely to be wrong and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You did not allocate memory for `curr` before using it. Two options:

1. Make `curr` point to an instance of `item`:

   ```
   item i;
   curr = &i;
   ```
2. Allocate memory dynamically for `curr` using `malloc`/`calloc`:

   ```
   curr = malloc(sizeof(*curr));
   /*OR*/
   curr = calloc( 1, sizeof(*curr));
   ```

   and later, free it after its use. It is also a good idea to check if `malloc`/`calloc` did not fail by checking its return value. It will return `NULL` on failure.